# Cognito - Refresh token has been revoked

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I'm using aws cognito user pool to authenticate users signing into our app. When we are testing, we are using the same credentials to sign in. I have set the refresh token expiry time as 10 years, while access and id tokens expiry time is set to 1 hour. But after sometime one or other person in the team getting **refresh token has been revoked and at times refresh token is expired**. Is this due to the same credentials being shared or for some other reason ?

Somebody please help me out to get a clarity on this.

Comment: What method or methods are you using to sign out users?

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'm using adminUserGlobalSignOut method.

Comment: that would be the reason tokens are getting revoked. The “global sign out” portion of that method means that it revokes ALL current active refresh tokens.

Comment: Yes I just referred it. Thanks.